# Laravel 5.2 Auth::login() isn't persisted

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I've moved from 5.1 to 5.2 today and wanted to get authentication to work. But it doesn't persist the login itself. I'm using Googles OAuth 2.0 and persisting the id and name in the database.

```
// OAuth flow..

Auth::loginUsingId($google_plus_id);

return redirect('/debug');
```

On the debug route I've only a `dd(auth()->user())`.
But this is always returning null after the redirect.

When I'm logging in and afterwards `dd()` the authenticated user, it works.
But redirecting to another route and it's `NULL`

I'm aware of the new *middleware-group* web and therefore my routes.php is looking like this:

```
Route::group([ 'middleware' => [ 'web' ] ], function () {

  Route::get('/auth/google', [
      'as'   => 'google.login',
      'uses' => 'Auth\OAuthController@getGoogleRedirect'
  ]);

  Route::get('/auth/google/callback', [
      'as'   => 'google.callback',
      'uses' => 'Auth\OAuthController@getGoogleCallback'
  ]);

    Route::get('/debug', function(){
        dd(auth()->user());
    });
});
```

The auth.php config file is adjusted, too.

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Http\Models\GooglePlusUser::class,
    ],
],
```

And the GooglePlusUser class is using the authenticatable trait. This whole setup worked fine in L5.1 but somehow it's messing around in 5.2 and I can't seem to find why.

Comment: The only thing I can thing of (and keep in mind that this could be wrong or not helpful) is in your config folder, in the session.php file, there is a lifetime attribute. If that is set to 0, it would log you out immediately after logging you in.

Comment: Sadly it's not the case, as I thought of this, too. It's the default 120 minutes value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont know why it's happening, maybe the base Eloquent Model was changed itself, but it treated the identifier as **integer** causing the max value of an integer. However, google's id is 21 characters long therefore saved in the database as string, not an int. Applying a mutator in the GooglePlusUser class to stringify it solved it.

**EDIT:** Seems like its line 2690 in the Eloquent Model which references to this function:

```
public function getCasts()
{
    if ($this->incrementing) {
        return array_merge([
            $this->getKeyName() => 'int',
        ], $this->casts);
    }

    return $this->casts;
}
```

**EDIT 2:** An easier approach than using a mutator is using `protected $casts = [ 'id' => 'string' ];` [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting)